# does python ftp storbinary function have a return value?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm newbie to `python`, I'm looking to some examples to use FTP in `python` and found this instruction in a working program:

```
if ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file, inpFile)>0:
 count+=1
```

My question is about the if condition, how can it works ? I cannot find anywhere in the documentation of `python` that `storbinary` returns some kind of value.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a return value from the storbinary (at least in python 3.4).

If the transfer was a success, you should get back "226 Transfer complete" from the function when done.